# Как определить к какой рабочей группе относится пользователь

Tags: python-3.x, windows

В windows по умолчанию такая группа стоит как "WORKGROUP". Так вот мне надо с помощью python узнать принадлежность пользователя к группе.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
import win32net

def CheckGroupMembership(group, member):
    members = win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(None, group, 1)
    return member.lower() in list(map(lambda d: d['name'].lower(), members[0]))  
# Проверяем:
print(if_user_in_group('WORKGROUP', 'vicont'))
```